# IntelliSense for React Native when Importing or adding libraries

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to add IntelliSense when I'm importing or adding libraries from `'react-native'`. I just do not know what is it called. Can someone help me out here.

The IntelliSense I want is like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For IntelliSense you has to install extensions,

You can install extensions from [image: here]

As per my experience **React Native Tools,React Native snippet, Prettier**(For formatting code) are good extensions. You can search from top search bar

If you habit of eclipse shortcuts then you can install **eclipse keymap** similarly intellij keymap is also available if you are familiar with Android studio.

If you want to debug app then **Node debug** is good extension.

EDIT: example
[image]

Comment: Is that gonna give me the same IntelliSense I want that looks like in the image?

Comment: yes of course it will. Restart  VS after installing extensions. For your case React Native Tools,React Native snippet are enough

Comment: It looks not. I tried to import 'Touches' but nothing intelliSense showed, because there is so many kind of 'Touches'

Comment: There is no touches you can use TouchableOpacity that is commonaly used for touch

Comment: No, you do not get me. I want is the IntelliSense, i'm just explaining it to you. I want to show intelliSense when I type 'Touch' then all kinds of Touch will show just like in the image I post.

Comment: its showing me...yes you can see all type of touch. see my edited answer

Comment: What is that extension is called? Is it the React Native Tools?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.vscode-react-native  React native tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181534/discussion-between-rajesh-nasit-and-liza-catherine-ombyaw).